# Is there a way to join a train/test split in a Dataset?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dataset

the dataset I'm working with already has 2 csv-Files for the train/test split. To do some preprocessing before training, I wanted to join the 2 Datasets to save a bit of code, like this:

```
DatasetDict({
    train: Dataset({
        features: ['Unnamed: 0', 'label', 'text', 'enocded_labels'],
        num_rows: 840
    })
    test: Dataset({
        features: ['Unnamed: 0', 'label', 'text', 'enocded_labels'],
        num_rows: 360
    })
```

But all the `concat()` and `append()` methods from the Datasets and Pandas libraries gave me 1 big joined Dataset like that:

```
Dataset({
    features: ['index', 'label', 'text'],
    num_rows: 1228
})
```

So i wanna know if there is a way to join the 2 splits, so that i can have them in a Dataset with 2 seperate entries.

Thank you!